# Powershell - Adding a Month to all files in a folder

Tags: powershell

a complete newbie to Powershell here.

What I am attempting to do is using Powershell, adding a month for the creationtime of files in a folder, which is based off the current creation date of the document, as opposed to the get-date system date.

Edit to how I get it to work for single documents:

I managed to get it to work for a specific file using this command:

```bsh
$(get-item test.txt).creationtime=$(Get-item test.txt).creationtime.AddMonths(1)
```

Rather than specify each filer individually, I want to do the same as above but for all documents in a folder.

Comment: Unclear what you mean.. Do you want to add 1 month as of the **current** date, or add a month to the file's **LastWriteTime** date?

Comment: Essentially what I am trying to do, is amend the lastwrite or creationdate of multiple documents without having to refer to each file individually

Comment: Well... see my answer then. It iterates through files in a folder and adjusts the LastWriteTime on each of them. If you rather change the `CreationTime`, tat's up to you

Answer (score 2):

If the question is to add 1 month to the LastWriteTime date of each file, instead of setting the LastWriteTime date to a date 1 month away from the **current** system date, you can do

```
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path 'PathToWhereTheFilesAre' -File)) {
    $file.LastWriteTime = $file.LastWriteTime.AddMonths(1)
}
```

If it is the current system date plus 1 month you want, you can use any of the answers given already by both [Klausen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63787663/9898643) and [Venkataraman R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63787206/9898643)

Answer (score 1):

You can go for foreach loop to iterate over files and update the lastwritetime

```bsh
$FolderName = "c:\dev"
foreach($file in (GEt-childitem -Path $FolderName ))
{
$file.lastwritetime=$(Get-Date).AddMonths(1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define which files you want to apply this "addmonths". In the code sample I added two parameters you may want to remove, just in case you need them.

Thanks.

```
# Folder where your files are located
$folder = 'C:\Temp\'

# Create list of files to go thru. 
# -Recurse option will navigate in the folders recursively. 
# -File can be used so no folders are picked up in your script
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse -File

# Iterate file by file in the results
foreach($file in $files)
{
    $file.lastwritetime=$(Get-Date).AddMonths(1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help!

I've used your guidance and created the following code which does exactly what I want it to do:

```bsh
$folder = "C:\Users\ajames\Powershell"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse -File
foreach($file in $files)
{$file.creationtime=$($file.CreationTime.AddDays(1)) }
```

Cheers again.

Comment: Please mark it as answer, so it is helpful for others in future